# LZ77 using the suffix tree

Tags: suffix-tree, lz77

I have some problems understanding of how to effectively use the suffix tree in LZ77 with a sliding window, especially with deleting the suffix.

I seems that if I have the window of length *m* I need to always remove the suffixes with length greater than *m*, however the procedure can take *O(m)* to remove the whole suffix, so it takes a lot of time. Can anyone explain greater solution or give a useful link? Thanks in advance!